# android studio build AVD unknown error

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

[image]

and

[image]

my PC cpu(E3-1231v3),vt is already.And,I am a tiro.I can't  solve this problem.Can anyone give me some advice? thank you.

Comment: "Consider using AVD with Google API" seems self explanatory to me. Open the SDK manager, or find the IDE logs

Comment: I do not have 10 prestige to show you the SDK manager.But HAXM has been installed.

Comment: I'm not talking about HAXM, or the intel system images. There are some that say "Google API"

Answer (score 8):

I've just solved the problem by deleting *.ini files from a directory home//.android/avd
It's for Ubuntu.
In Windows it's also in the user's folder (.android/avd).

Comment: home/_your name_/.android/avd

Answer (score 7):

**install "vc_redist.x64.exe"**

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

> Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015, 2017 and
>   2019

I had this "unknown" error today under Windows 10 as well. There was a new Android Studio version and a new emulator. I first renamed the folder ".AndroidStudio3.5" ("C:\Users[YourName]") and old settings not imported. I tried reinstalling the emulator this way.

[Unable to run mksdcard.exe SDK tool android v3.5.2 at windows10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59182493/unable-to-run-mksdcard-exe-sdk-tool-android-v3-5-2-at-windows10)

Because of **"mksdcard.exe"** error this was not possible. I installed **"vc_redist.x64.exe"** and could use the old folder ".AndroidStudio3.5" again.

Comment: It seems that there are many reasons for this. In my case I was in a fresh windows 10 installation and it failed. This answer saved my time. Thanks

Comment: OK thanks. Reinstalling Android Studio will not always work.

Comment: Many thanks! That was the cause in my case. May God bless you!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue because AvdManagerConnection "Failed to create sdcard in the AVD folder."

The reason of it was missing VCRUNTIME140.dll

I've solved it by installing Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable Update from Microsoft website.

Comment: This fixed my issue. I think there are many different reasons and ways to fix this generic error. This was mine. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and its seems like you did not installed Google API Library.

Just confirm that have you installed all Intel Image Library and Google API for your desired API.

Just go to your SDK Manager and check intel system images is installed or not if not then you have to installed it as well install Google API Library.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error after my Windows PC crashed while creating a new virtual device.

**Reinstalling** Android Studio solved the problem in my case.

It took less than 10 minutes. After that the error disappeared and I was able to create virtual device without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the C++ library to ger rid out of the error.Which you can find from here [you can download and install from here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-pk/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was my file structure, in particular the "emulator" directory. For some reason, Android SDK manager was installing packages in a nested structure that Android Studio wasn't recognizing.

What fixed it was de-nesting my "emulator" directory.

My old Android SDK structure:

ANDROID_HOME

- emulator

  - package.xml
  - emulator

    - (all the important stuff: _CodeSignature, android-info.txt, bin64...) <- move this to the parent directory
- (other directories: build-tools, cmdline-tools, platforms, sources, etc.)

I moved "all the important stuff" to the top-level "emulator" directory and deleted the nested directory.

My new Android SDK structure:

ANDROID_HOME

- emulator

  - package.xml
  - (all the important stuff)
- (other directories)

I had already done this for other directories before I encountered this problem, so you may need to do the same for any other nested directories you may have.

I'm using Android Studio Flamingo on MacOS 13 with my Android SDK on an external hard drive.