# Unknown error while creating AVD in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-virtual-device

AVD Manager in my android studio was working fine, until an unexpected shutdown caused AVD Manager to act weird. Now I can't run any AVD's.

When I click any system-image it says `unknown error` under  recommendation. When I click finish it says:

> An error occurred while creating the AVD. See Idea.log for more details.

Here are the screenshots:

[image: AVD Manager screenshot]

[image: Shows when click troubleshoot]

[image: Shows when click finish]

Comment: and what does `idea.log` say?

Comment: idea.log says : WARN - vdmanager.AvdManagerConnection - Exception during AvdManager initialization: java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem resolved by reinstalling android studio

Comment: I reinstall, but still facing  the same issue.

Comment: Maybe clearing the avd image might do , also try other solutions

Answer (score 3):

I deep dive into this  issue and found the following solution.
There was a problem to run mksdcard sdk tool. Some SDK tools such as mksdcard.exe require Microsoft Visual C++ runtime. So go to your System properties and check your System type:

[image]

Then based on your system type,(for me it was x64) download/update the latest Microsoft Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2019 from the link https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

[image]

After installing Microsoft Visual C++, the problem was fixed. Also the Unknown error problem was fixed and I was able to create the avd successfully.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to solve this using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46332056/8817991).

> [Delete] *.ini files from a directory home//.android/avd It's for
>   Ubuntu. In Windows it's also in the user's folder (.android/avd).

Comment: Widnows location C:\Users\UserName\.android\avd

Answer (score 0):

First, go to control panel,
Remove, if exists Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable package x86 or x64,

Then, go to this link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/latest-supported-vc-redist?view=msvc-170

download Visual Studio 2015,2017,2019,2022 latest package x86 and x64 version. Install two version then,
restart pc,
Error is gone...

Answer (score 0):

One possible reason is that adb.exe is blocked by your organisation's Group Policy.

You can check this by looking in the `idea.log` file. Go to Help -> Show Log in Explorer.

```
2023-04-03 15:37:43,629 [  60269]   WARN - #c.a.ddmlib - Cannot run program "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe": CreateProcess error=1260, This program is blocked by group policy. For more information, contact your system administrator
```